# Client datetime vs Server datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# Web application which has been installed in the US Server and database is in another server. I am accessing my application from India. Now when user sign up, he choose the Reporting date from the calender control which has the current system date time selected by default and User Creation date is inserted from the background C# code. Since I am using the application in my local country browser, that's why both the dates are different. Is there anyway to resolve this conflicts.

```
obUser.CreationDate = Datetime.Now
```

Comment: Can you explain with example and what is your problem as such ?

Comment: Be sure that all the `DateTime`s in your database are always *stored* in UTC time zone (`UtcNow` instead of just `Now`) and all the communication between the application and the database also uses UTC time zone and wherever you *display* the `DateTime` to the user, use `utcDateTime.ToLocalTime()`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `DateTime.Now` use: `DateTime.UtcNow`. UtcNow is acording to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx):

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on
>   this computer, expressed as the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Answer (score 2):

There have also:

```
obUser.CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Look on:
[Converting DateTime.Now To A Different Time Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872980/converting-datetime-now-to-a-different-time-zone)

```
TimeZoneInfo maltaTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("...");
DateTime utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime malta = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, maltaTimeZone )
```

List of TimeZone
[List of Timezone ID's for use with FindTimeZoneById() in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (TimeZoneInfo z in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
        Console.WriteLine(z.Id);
}
```

Comment: UtcNow is not return exact time, if your server is in non US

Comment: UTC return UTC time you must convert to your TimeZone.